# Error builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' using pickle

Tags: python, file, pickle

```
data = {'fire_rate':fire_rate, 'player_health_max':player_health_max, 'player_health':player_health, 'dmg_multiplier':dmg_multiplier}
with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)       
with open('savefile') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

gives the error `builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` on line `data = pickle.load(f)`
I tried changing `with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:` to `with open('savefile', 'w') as f:` but then I get the error  `write() argument must be str, not bytes` on the `with open` line. The only reason I can think my original code doesn't work is that 'fire_rate' and 'player_health_max' are strings and not byte-like objects. I am doing this as to save the variables so that the player can leave the game, then rejoin and have all the same stats.

Comment: Open the file for readin in the binary mode `open('savefile', "rb")`

Answer (score 0):

Change `with open('savefile') as f:` to `with open('savefile', 'rb') as f:`.

Comment: This stops the error, but doesn't actually change the variables I want to change when I read the savefile

Comment: @OwenPenn What do you mean *change*?